# Merge cells using "google-spreadsheet" npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I had to do some work with google sheets api and i found this popular package on npm to ease my work https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet .
I have done my entire project with this package but then i was asked to do some formating to the spreadsheet (merging cells for exemple).
The problem is that i haven't found anything interresting in the doc https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/ (about this subject).
Does anyone knows how to format cells using this package ?
Is it even possible ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can make a request to the sheets API to do this.

- Have a read at this example of [merging cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting#merge_cells) with the Google sheets API.

Your app needs [authorization](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) though.

Which you can get by following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114435/4243927).