# How to handle “App is temporarily blocked from logging in with your Google account” barrier

Tags: api, authentication, verification, gdrive

I am using [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) and [gshell](https://github.com/wkentaro/gshell) in order to interact with my Google account and download files, get their info.

When I run: `gdrive about` or `gdown about`, I get following message

```
Initializing system (/home/user/.gdrive)
Authentication needed
Go to the following url in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=...... \
apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=....

Enter verification code:
```

---

Afterwards, I keep getting following error message, when I pasted the URL starting with `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=` on my browser:

`This app is temporarily blocked from logging in with your Google account`.

[image]

==>  This error was not generated before and I was able to receive the `verification code`, in order to use to connect into my account.

Is it possible to overcome this barrier of Google in order to use `gdrive` or `gdown`?

---

The example of generated token.json, after the verification code is pasted.

```
  "access_token": ".....",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "1/....",
  "expiry": "2020-12-21T02:..."
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to overcome the google barrier. Have you done any changes to your google account in order for Google to block the app for you? Also, have you tried to setup a test account and check if the error occurs as well on another account?

Comment: I have tried with multiple accounts (even a completely new one) but there was no affect. I am not sure can I overcame this issue using `rclone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tellowkrinkle's [comment](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/commit/31d0829c180795d17e00b7a354fffe4d72be712b#commitcomment-45165924) help me to solve the issue.

> Probably yes. I have the old binary and Google blocks it from
> authenticating, saying that it's dangerous and they blocked it for my
> safety (thanks a lot). It looks like Google now requires you to let
> them review applications that want to access sensitive information
> through their API
>
> If you want to use it for yourself, you will need to:
>
> 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com and create a new project for yourself
> 2. Search for the `Google Drive API` in the search box at the top, and enable it
> 3. Click `OAuth consent screen` on the left and set it up.
>
>    - Assuming your account isn't part of an organization, you'll have to say your app is for `external` users and in testing
>    - In the required scopes section, add `.../auth/docs` and `.../auth/drive` (I'm not sure which needed, it's probably only one of
>      those). This will probably not be available if you didn't complete (2)
>    - Add the accounts you want to use with your copy of gdrive as testers of your app. Only these accounts will be able to use your copy
>      of gdrive, so everyone will have to compile their own (unless someone
>      goes and gets theirs reviewed by Google)
> 4. Click `Credentials` on the left, then Create Credentials, then OAuth client ID. The application type is `Desktop app`
> 5. Copy the Client ID and Secret into handlers_drive.go lines 17 and 18 and compile the application

---

```
$ git clone https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive.git
$ cd gdrive
$ nano handlers_drive.go
# Copy the Client ID and Secret into handlers_drive.go lines 17 and 18 and compile the application
$ mv ~/.gdrive/token_v2.json ~/.gdrive/token_v2.json.old
$ go get github.com/prasmussen/gdrive
$ go build -ldflags "-w -s"
$ cp gdrive $GOPATH/bin/gdrive
$ gdrive about 
Go to the following url in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=.....

Enter verification code:
```

---

Guide:

- [TUTORIAL: How to get rid of 403 Errors](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/issues/426)
- https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/issues/426#issuecomment-459150627
- https://github.com/marufshidiq/gdrive-cli-builder