# Container-bound script is suddenly saying "app is blocked" when attempting to run anything at all

Tags: google-apps-script

Up until today, I've been able to test functions in a container-bound script without issue. However, once I pulled in a standalone script as a library, things have gone awry. (Note that the library uses OAuth2 for read/write access to a GCP resource.)

Now, after going through the permissioning and consent flow, I get a "this app is blocked" message (screenshot below) any time I try to run *anything* in the bound script. I removed the library to see if that would help but it did not.

The bound script's scopes are displayed as follows:

```
OAuth Scope required by script:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

[image: App is blocked screenshot]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you activate "Advanced  protection" in your Google account?

Comment: No, I do not have Advanced Protection activated.

Comment: You might have to create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I did just that!

Comment: Consider adding a answer with the link to the issue for wider audience or stars

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316819/unable-to-open-google-xlsx-spreadsheet-also-google-drive-permission-blocked [ ]