# Google blocks my Google Script that reads info from my Google Sheet to make slides in Google Slide project

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this Google Script with a Google Slides project.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ssURL = 'URL FOR GOOGLE SHEET HERE';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssURL);
  var deck = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getRange('A1:E368').getValues();
  var slides = deck.getSlides();
  var templateSlide = slides[0];
  var presLength = slides.length;

  values.forEach(function(p){
    Logger.log(p)
}
```

When I click "Run" on the Google Script I get a message saying "This project requires your permission to access your data." When I click "Review permissions," a new browser window pops up to allow me to sign into my Google Account. But when I did, I got this error message:

"This app is blocked"

"This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access."

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66633659

Comment: Check this answer specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701477/555121 you may have to switch to other google cloud project