# How can I run the google appscript blocked by my google account security?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-account

I'm facing an issue with a basic Google Apps Script that I wrote. The script is intended for crawling a webpage to extract a specific value, and it does not handle any sensitive personal data. However, I'm unable to run the script because my Google account has blocked it, citing concerns about saving sensitive personal data.

I've already done some research and found a similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66633659/can-not-run-trivial-app-script-bound-to-new-blank-document-get-this-app-is-bl) , but haven't found a viable solution yet. The error message I'm getting is "This app is blocked", and it's preventing me from executing even this basic script.

Could anyone provide insights or suggest how to resolve this issue? Is there a way to reassure Google's security protocols that my script is safe and does not violate any privacy or security guidelines?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[turning "Allow less secure apps"](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) is not available for 2FA account.

Comment: I am not quite sure with your concern, like is this the first time you have encountered that error? is this a bound or standalone script? , have you tried recreating your script in a brandnew project, just copy and paste everything then try running again? or have you seen this: [“This App Is Blocked” Error On Google Apps Script:Solution](https://aimanfikri.com/2022/05/09/this-app-is-blocked-error-on-google-apps-script-solution/) and [link](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/99ukVbFi71g?pli=1)

Comment: Oh sorry. This is my first time writing AppScripts, and this is code I wrote in a completely new, empty project.

Comment: I understand but have you seen the links I've shared and tried to follow the instructions there?