How do we avoid the "Cannot access your Google account" error when embedding an editable Google Sheet in an iFrame?
We have a web application for solving puzzles as a team, and we use Google Sheets as part of our puzzle-solving setup. We simply embed an editable Google Sheet doc in an iFrame on each puzzle page, and folks are added as editors to that sheet (the rest of the page around the iframe has various metadata about the puzzle being solved). While most folks can see and edit the sheet in the iFrame just fine, certain individuals get a cryptic error ("Cannot access your Google account right now"). They are still able to open and edit the same sheet in a new browser tab, however.
We have isolated the issue to a very simple repro case -- just an iframe on an empty static page -- although we can only repro it for the certain folks in question, of course. It clearly has something to do with their Google account configuration, because it breaks no matter what browser they use, and doesn't break when they use alternative accounts.
What individual Google account configuration or setting could be causing this issue? To the best of our knowledge, the accounts that have this issue are personal ones, and not associated with Workspace accounts.

Hard to tell, some of these workarounds may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701477/

I see that there is a comment on your post containing a link with a workaround, and also an answer was posted. Kindly check if these will help you solve your problem. If it does, consider accepting the answer.

I think that may happen if the user is signed in to two or more Google accounts in the same web browser simultaneously.
Instruct them to sign out from all accounts, then sign in with a single account, and try again. See Fix issues with multiple Google Accounts.
To get notified of status changes of this bug, star issue 69270374 in the issue tracker. Click the star icon ☆ in the top left-hand corner to vote for fixing the issue. Please do not post a "me too" or "+1" reply, but just click the star icon. Google prioritizes issues with the most stars.
