# Google Spreadsheet Script Trigger: This app is blocked

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a trigger for a script in google spreadsheet and upon trying to save the trigger I am getting the following error:

[image]

> This app is blocked This app tried to access sensitive info in your
> Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

I don't have G-Suite, I don't have an organization, I am simply using my personal Gmail account. I don't have the special account protection thing enabled. I tried using different scripts, even an empty script.
What could be the problem here? I have used scripts and add-ons in the past, but haven't needed triggers yet. Is there another way to run a script daily or monthly, without this trigger functionality?

Answer (score 2):

### There is currently a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/180436121)

I recommend oyu to "star" it to increase visibility, so it hopefully gets fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks, I starred it. This seems to be related to Gsuite though, which I am not using. Are script triggers only available on gsuite? Is that the problem?

Comment: No, script triggers are available for any user account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Unable to open Google xlsx spreadsheet / Also Google Drive permission Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316819/unable-to-open-google-xlsx-spreadsheet-also-google-drive-permission-blocked)

The same solution logic can solve this problem.

[ ]