# No "authorize" prompt appears when I try to share a Google Sheet with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to share a Google Sheet with a bound apps script. I've tried testing it with my other google accounts, and the "authorize" prompt works correct. However, when other users try to run the bound script, they see this:

[image]

Why are they seeing this prompt instead of the proper authorization dialog? How can I allow others to use the script?

Comment: welcome to Google's world, where this issue is "intended behavior" - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820

Comment: this answer may be more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701477 (from a duplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to open Google xlsx spreadsheet / Also Google Drive permission Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316819/unable-to-open-google-xlsx-spreadsheet-also-google-drive-permission-blocked)

Comment: Are you having that problem on regular gmail.com accounts or in Google workspace accounts?

Comment: @GabrielCarballo regular gmail accounts. the shared accounts can access the sheet correctly, they just can't run the script

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is being investigated again as [Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555121/kos) mentioned, look at this [issuetracker](https://%20https://issuetracker.google.com/181220763), last update was on Feb 15.

I'll recommend starring at this tracker and submitting your scenario to the issuetracker as well, you may as well try the following:

> Add the following line to the top of the file /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

There are other work arounds provided in the thread that may work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but none of the work arounds are working for me. My team is currently just copy-pasting the scripts to our respective accounts. Still waiting for an official fix or official guidance.

Comment: Also, I can sometimes run scripts correctly from other peoples sheets, but they can't from mine.