# How to uploading file to user's google drive storage in the device in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, google-drive-api, ionic3

I am trying to implement a feature which will allow user's to save a file in their device but not only in the device storage but to google drive or dropbox storage as well.

It seems there is not much information out there, the only 2 plugins i found they seem to require credentials to access these API's but i don't have control to user google token or Client ID. However i haven't tried it yet, i wanted to get an opinion from your experience on what to use.

What do you think can best work for my Ionic 3 project. I want user's to be able to save and read a file from their google drive or dropbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your **app** will always require the **user consent** to access the Drive API on  user's behalf and save the file for them.

This means you need to [create a project in the Google developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111361/how-to-download-a-google-drive-file-using-python-and-the-drive-api-v3/60114435#60114435), and enable the Drive API scopes that your app will require.

After that, when your user gives your app consent, your app will get the valid credentials, that you can pickle and reuse.