# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "***" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, google-drive-api, backup

I am using google drive api with laravel for a continuous backup, so I am using following packages

> "nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive": "~1.1", and

> "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.14"

I have set up google drive api v3 with refresh token and put it into .env

```
FILESYSTEM_CLOUD=google
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID=****.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET=****
GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN=****
GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID=****
```

so everything works properly, and I can use google drive as a disk to store the back up everyday through a cron job, the only problem is after a week the refresh token gets expired(I assume) and stops working with this error message,

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "****" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
```

if I change the refresh token again from [oathplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) and place it into `.env` it starts working again for a week.

so how can I solve this problem thus I need not to generate the token every week.

Comment: in oauth, did you make token auto refresh?

Comment: yes I have checked 'Auto-refresh the token before it expires' before exchanging authorization code for tokens

Comment: how do you get the refreshtoken. may you show snap of the code?

Comment: I got it through oauth play ground

Comment: you should have another way to get it before calling API, and if it's expired you should update yours. Don't depend on env file. you need to add it to a db to be able to update it each time it's not valid.

Comment: may be this token is handled by `nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive` package, so they need it on env file

Comment: you will handle that from the config for sure, instead of depending on the value from .env, you will get the values from the db and add it

Answer (score 1):

Oauth playground is only intended to be used for testing. Tokens created on the playground will only work for about two weeks.

You should implement your own authorization.

Comment: how to do that, can you refer any documentation r blog that might be helpful for me

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the OAuthPlayground that it will ***revoke*** authorization tokens after 24 hours.

[image: Note OAuthPlayground].

The process of setting up a GCP project, consent screen and authorization is the same for all programming languages. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114435/4243927) for step by step guide to authorization.

Comment: yes I already have the access token as that answer demonstrated, but I need the refresh token as access token has limited life time

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline you can refresh your access tokens too